# Can I control minifacation in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, glsl

Say I have a 512x512 pixels texture that I am displaying on 256x256 pixels on the screen.
In that case "the level-of-detail function used when sampling from the texture determines that the texture should be minified" according to my `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` which is `GL_LINEAR`.
As a result 2x2 pixels will be minified to 1 pixel (distance weighted linear average).
Is there some way that I can control the minification?
Say I instead want 4x4 or 8x8 pixels to be minified to 1 pixel since I prefer a coarse or rasterized image ;-).

Alternatively is there some way I can achieve the same effect in the shader code?

Comment: If you just want to read from a higher mipmap level, have a look at the `textureLod` method where you can specify from which level you want to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to precisely control the filtering, write an appropriate fragment shader, use the `texelFetch` function to access the unfiltered texture data, then implement the filter in the shader.

If you're going for a Taylor approximation of the filtering kernel, keep in mind, that you can make use of bilinear mipmap filtering (i.e. `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER := GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR`) to implement the 0th and 1st order terms of the Taylor expansion.